# Attribute slicing using XPATH?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

Lets assume we have following html snippet:

```
...
<section>
    <a href="https://example.com" data-utag="{"sku":"12340", "abc":"Lorem ipsum"}">sometext</a>
</section>
...
```

Using XPATH, how can I extract only SKU value (which is **12340**) from the data-utag?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. That snippet isn't part of a well-formed XML document, owing to the abuse of `"`.

Comment: If all such values are like that, you can access the whole value through `node.attrib["data-utag"]` and use `eval(value)` to read it as a Python dictionary. Or you can do some quick and dirty string splitting.

Comment: Ignoring the quote problem, you can use regular expressions with xpath (see)[http://regular-expressions.mobi/xpath.html], so maybe. It depends on whether the data format. This exact string, sure, but if it's something like a string representation of a python dict, then in general it needs a parser.

Comment: I did not come up on the structure but SKU is valuable data for me. This example is taken from one of the market places. They use data-utag which holds a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes instead of double in html's tags will make this [parsel](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel)/scrapy script work:

```
from parsel import selector
import json

sel = selector.Selector(text=u"""<section><a href='https://example.com' data-utag='{"sku":"12340", "abc":"Lorem ipsum"}'>sometext</a></section>""")

jsontxt = sel.xpath("string(.//section/a/@data-utag)").extract()[0]

loaded = json.loads(jsontxt)

print(loaded["sku"])
```